# Which of the following statements are true for $A=\{t\sin(\frac{1}{t})\ |\ t\in (0,\frac{2}{\pi})\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A=\{t\sin(\frac{1}{t})\ |\ t\in (0,\frac{2}{\pi})\}$.

Then

1. $\sup (A)<\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{1}{n\pi}$ for all $n\ge 1$.
2. $\inf (A)> \frac{-2}{3\pi}-\frac{1}{n\pi}$ for all $n\ge 1$.
3. $\sup (A)=1$
4. $\inf (A)=-1$

My answer was options $1$ and $2$ which matched with prelim answer key provided by organization, but the final answer key changed the answer to option $1$ only. Why is option $2$ not correct?

**My attempt-**

As $-t\le t\sin(1/t)\le t$. So  $t\sin(1/t)$ will always be less than $\frac{2}{\pi}$ which is strictly less than $1$. So option $3$ is false and option $1$ is true. Also value of $t\sin(1/t)$ is always greater than or equal to $-2/\pi=-0.63$, so infimum cannot be $-1$.

Now at $t=2/3\pi$ , function has value $\frac{-2}{3\pi}$. So if option $2$ is false we must have some value of $t$ in $A$ for which the function attains value strictly less than $\frac{-2}{3\pi}$. Right?

Can you please help me with option $2$ now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us some work.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 please see edit.

Comment: Are you sure it's $-1/(n\pi)$ in option $2$ and not $+1/(n\pi)$ ?

Comment: @Thinking yes...

Comment: Thx for pinging me.  Close vote removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the option $2$ is true, it means that $$\inf A\ge -{2\over 3\pi}$$ since $\inf A> -{2\over 3\pi}-{1\over n\pi}$ is true for all $n>1$. Since $$\large t\sin {1\over t}\Big|_{t={2\over 3\pi}\in A}=-{2\over 3\pi}$$ then we must have $\inf A= -{2\over 3\pi}$ and $$\large {d\over dt}t\sin {1\over t}\Big|_{t={2\over 3\pi}\in A}=0$$ because the infimum is equal to minimum now (since it is attained in $t={2\over 3\pi}\in A$) and as the function is differentiable in $A$. But this doesn't hold since $$\large {d\over dt}t\sin {1\over t}\Big|_{t={2\over 3\pi}\in A}=\large \sin {1\over t}-{1\over t}\cos {1\over t}\Big|_{t={2\over 3\pi}}=-1\ne 0$$therefore option $2$ is incorrect.

Comment: (you have functions of $t$ but you evaluate at $x=...$)

Comment: Thank you for heads up. That was a typo....

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $\sin(1/t)$ turns at $t=2/3\pi$, but this is not true of $t\sin(1/t)$. Multiplying by $t$ has the effect of pushing the minimum point to the right and down slightly.

[image] [image]
Since $a>b-\frac{1}{\pi n}$ for all $n\ge 1$ iff $a\ge b$, we are done.

To see this without a graph, lets start from your correct observation that for $f(t) = t\sin (1/t)$, $f(2/3\pi) = -2/3\pi$. The derivative at this point however is
$$ f'(3\pi/2) = \sin(3\pi/2) + 2/3\pi \cos(3\pi/2) = -1  $$

Since $f$ is smooth on a small neighbourhood of $2/3\pi$, $f'\le -1/2<0$ on this neighbourhood. Thus $f$ is decreasing at $2/3\pi$.

Something slightly more general is true:

> Suppose $f$ is smooth, $f(1)=0=f(2)$, $f\le 0$ and $f$ has a unique non degenerate minimum point $x_0$ in $[1,2]$. Then $g(x)=xf(x)$ has a minimum point to the right and below of $x_0$.

Proof- by a similar computation to the above, $g$ is decreasing at $x_0$. As $g(2)=2f(2)=0$, we conclude by Intermediate Value Theorem and Rolles' Theorem.

Comment: Can you prove it using the first derivative test?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 do you mean the claim that the minimum is pushed to the right?

Comment: Yes, thx for edit.

Answer (score 1):

Like some other answers, but written differently:

Let $f(t)= t\sin(1/t).$ Then $f'(t)= \sin(1/t) - [\cos (1/t)]/t$ for $t>0.$ Thus $f'(2/(3\pi)) = -1.$ Hence for $t$ near and to the right of $2/(3\pi),$ we have

$$\frac{f(t)-f(2/(3\pi)}{t-2/(3\pi)}<-\frac{1}{2}.$$

For such $t$ we have $f(t)<f(2/(3\pi)=-2/(3\pi).$ Hence $\inf A <-2/(3\pi),$ which implies 2. does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1/t\implies A=\{\frac{\sin x}x:x>\pi/2\}$

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x, x>\pi/2$

$f(3\pi/2)=-\frac2{3\pi}<0, f'(3\pi/2)>0\implies f$ is strictly increasing at $3\pi/2$

This means you can find $a\in\varepsilon-$neighbourhood of $3\pi/2$ such that $f(a)<f(3\pi/2)\implies f(a)<-\frac2{3\pi}$

Comment: This is wrong. The fact that $f'(a) < 0$ doesn't mean there is a neighbourhood of $a$ where the function is strictly decreasing. Take for example : $x\mapsto x+10x^2\sin(1/x)$

Comment: at $0$ it doesn't verify what you are saying

Comment: $\sin x/x$ is continuously differentiable for $x>\pi/2$

Comment: That's not my point. Look at my first comment.

Comment: The result holds for continuously differentiable functions. $x+10x^2\sin(1/x)$ is not continuously differentiable at $0$.

Comment: It is continuous since we can easily extend the function at the point $0$.

Comment: Continuously differentiable means that the function is differentiable (and thus continuous) and its derivative is continuous.

Comment: @Thinking note $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\sin(1/x)) = -\cos(1/x)+... \notin C^0$